# php возврат html пользовательской функцией

Tags: php, html

Привет, хочу вывести через функцию таблицу:

```
<?
    function foo($array){
        return '<table><tr>
           <td>'.$array['val'].'</td>
           <td>'.$array['bar'] + $array['num'].'</td>
           </tr></table>';
    }
?>
```

html страница

```
<html>
...
<? $array = array('val'=>5, 'bar'=>8, 'num'=>3); ?>
<? print foo($array); ?>
...
</html>
```

но что-то идет не так, и выводятся некоторые числа без табличных тегов, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Экранировать данные не пробовали перед вставкой в html? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Что на выходе получается? Приведите код.

Comment: @Visman, данные не экранирую, массив который передается в функцию содержит подготовленные данные

Comment: Всем спасибо, нашел ответ сам, проблема оказалась в арифметической операции в функции, ее нужно взять в скобки, правда не могу понять зачем (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с приоритетом/порядком выполнения операций.

```
'<td>'.$array['bar'] + $array['num'].'</td>'
```

Если заглянем в [PHP: Приоритет операторов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php), то увидим, что операторы `.` и `+` имеют одинаковый приоритет и левую ассоциативность.

Это значит, что операции пройдут слева направо, по ходу кода.

То есть сначала у вас к строке `<td>` приконкатенируется число `8`, затем к получившейся строке `'<td>8'` прибавится число `3`. Строка в данном случае будет интерпретирована как число `0`.
В итоге получаем `0 + 3 = 3` и потерянную строку.

Поэтому, как вы уже сами разобрались, нужно расставлять скобки.

```
'<td>'.($array['bar'] + $array['num']).'</td>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, нашел ответ сам, проблема оказалась в арифметической операции в функции, ее нужно взять в скобки

```
<?
    function foo($array){
        return '<table><tr>
           <td>'.$array['val'].'</td>
           <td>'.($array['bar'] + $array['num']).'</td>
           </tr></table>';
    }
?>
```